# Changing the Default Vertical Page Position for a group of New Chapters with Patchcmd Command

Tags: vertical-alignment, chapters, etoolbox, patching, default

I am using the `patchcmd` command in the preamble to specify a vertical position default for where new (unnumbered) chapters should begin on the page:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Later in the same document, I would like to change that default to something else---and have attempted to use the same approach (after `\begin{document}`).

Although when I compile the code, I do not get an error, I am not successful at altering the previously specified default.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% For unnumbered chapters:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
INTRODUCTION.

\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Chapter 1}}
\lipsum[3]

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{150\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Chapter 2}}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The Chapter 1 is positioned as expected:

[image]

However, despite the change from `\vspace*{50\p@}` to `\vspace*{150\p@}`, there is no effect on the starting position of the (new) Chapter 2:

[image]

How may I change the default starting position for a group of new (un-numbered) chapters (say Chapters 2-5) in a document and then revert back to the original default (of `\vspace*{50\p@}` in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look the etoolbox [document](https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) page.13.

`\patchcmd[prefix]{command}{search}{replace}{success}{failure}`

`\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}`

According to your implementation, you patched the command `\@makeschapterhead` by search the string `\vspace*{50\p@}` and replace it by nothing.
So the second call of the command

`\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{150\p@}}{}{}{}`

was failed becuase there is no string `\vspace*{150\p@}` in `\@makeschapterhead` command.

The proper way to achieve what you want is as follow (I add `\@latex@info{true}` and `\@latex@info{false}` to show the patch result in the log file):

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% For unnumbered chapters:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{0\p@}}{\@latex@info{true}}{\@latex@info{false}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
INTRODUCTION.

\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Chapter 1}}
\lipsum[3]

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{0\p@}}{\vspace*{150\p@}}{\@latex@info{true}}{\@latex@info{true}}
\makeatother

\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Chapter 2}}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer and the link. If I wanted to revert back to the original condition as prescribed by `\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{0\p@}}{\@latex@info{true}}{\@latex@info{false}}` with the start of say, "Chapter 3", it seems that `\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{150\p@}}{\vspace*{0\p@}}{\@latex@info{true}}{\@latex@info{true}}` would do that for me; though I don't understand why `\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{150\p@}}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\@latex@info{true}}{\@latex@info{true}}`? I guess I'm having trouble grasping the explanation on page 13.

Comment: @jean-marie each time you patch the command, the command will become the <replace> the argument. Say If you start patch the command like this `\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{0\p@}}{}{}` So next time the patch <search> argument need to be `\vspace*{0\p@}`.

Comment: So, am I correct in inferring that putting `\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{150\p@}}{\vspace*{0\p@}}{\@latex@info{true}}{\@latex@info{true}}` before "Chapter 3" would position Chapter 3  as Chapter 1 was positioned?

Comment: @jean-marie Correct!

Comment: Many thanks! @Tom